# Filter dataframe group by not match to set

Tags: python, pandas

Given this dataframe and set:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'blah':['cats','cats','dogs','dogs','snakes','snakes','bears','bears'],
                   'foo':['A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A']})
   
    blah    foo
0   cats    A
1   cats    B
2   dogs    B
3   dogs    A
4   snakes  A
5   snakes  B
6   bears   A
7   bears   A

letters = set(['A', 'B'])

{'A', 'B'}
```

I want to filter the dataframe so that it includes only groups of `blah` where `set(foo)` does not match `letters`.

My expected result is:

```
    blah    foo
6   bears   A
7   bears   A
```

Below is the closest thing I've got, but I can't figure out how to compare to `letters`, and I don't want to return a DataFrame and not a Series.

```
df.groupby('blah')['foo'].apply(set)
```

Comment: any reason why you're using a set?

Comment: @Manakin I want to compare lists without being concerned about the order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer checks if the set of values within `foo` for each group are not equal to the `letters` set.  That is used to index the original data:

```
>>> mask = df.groupby('blah')['foo'].apply(lambda x: set(x) != letters)
>>> df[df['blah'].map(mask)]

    blah foo
6  bears   A
7  bears   A
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
df.loc[df['blah'].map(df.groupby('blah').agg(set)['foo'].ne(letters))]
```